# ASP.NET MVC Partiel view model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, model-binding

I am quite new to ASP.NET MVC, and I am working on a small quiz app project. However I am stuck with a rather annoying problem.

Right now I have a few models, with questions, choices and the quiz. The quiz is connected to a form. I use partial views in the forms to display each question, in the question I use another partial view to display the choices.

Whenever I try to get which answers were given from the form, I get 0 and null back. I have tried a lot of things, but none of them have worked.

Here are my classes

Choice

```
    public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswer { get; set; }
    private Question question = new Question();
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public Question Question
    {
        get { return question; }
        set { question = value; }
    }
}
```

Question

```
    public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private IList<Choice> choices = new List<Choice>();
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public IList<Choice> Choices
    {
        get { return choices; }
        set { choices = value; }
    }
}
```

Quiz

```
    public class Quiz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Question> Questions
    {
        get { return questions; }
        set { questions = value; }
    }
}
```

My controller. It does always set 'zzz' to null and 0's.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Grade(Quiz zzz)
    {
        var grade = quizService.Grade(zzz);
        return View(grade);
    }
```

The views. I used to not have the ViewDataDictionary, but that gave nulls too. I changed it to a ViewDataDictionary, but it still gives nulls back.

Note: I did add the comments right now, they are not in the actual code

Publish

```
@model QuizApp.Models.Quiz
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Publish";}

@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id)
@using (Html.BeginForm("Grade","Quiz", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var question in Model.Questions){
       @Html.Partial("_Question", question, new ViewDataDictionary(){
           TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()
           { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Questions" }
       });
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Vesturen" />
}
```

Question

```
@model QuizApp.Models.Question
<div class="question">
@Html.Hidden("Quiz.Questions[" + Model.OrderNumber + "].Id", Model.Id)

//Shows the question
<b>@Model.Text </b><br/> 

//Adds choices to the question
@foreach (var choice in Model.Choices)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Choice", choice, new ViewDataDictionary()
{
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()
    { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Choices" }
});
}
</div>
```

And finally the choice Partial view

```
@model QuizApp.Models.Choice

@Html.RadioButton("Quiz.Questions[" + Model.Question.OrderNumber + "].Choices[0].Id", Model.Id)
@Model.Text
```

Does anyone see a solution to my problem, or maybe a workaround? Did I do something wrong, that I obviously do not know about? I don't understand why it keeps giving me nulls, since it should be working now to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++){
   @Html.Partial("_Question", question, new ViewDataDictionary(){
       TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()
       { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Questions[" + i.ToString() + "]" }
   });
}
```

In other words, your field prefix needs to contain the index. Also, the index cannot be an arbitrary value, as you're attempting to do with `Model.Question.OrderNumber`. It needs to be the actual index within the list.

Alternatively, if you create the view `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Question.cshtml` along the lines of:

```
@model Namespace.To.Question

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
...
```

Then, in your view, you can simple do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)
```

And Razor will render that editor template for each item in `Questions`, all prefixed properly. Rinse and repeat with your other classes like `Choice`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! That alternative you give sounds a lot easier to do, I might do that in the future when I need to do something similar.